# Can't run phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 16 with Apache2 and PHP 7.0

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

When I try to open phpMyAdmin I get this error:

```
The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

`dpkg -l | grep php` gives me:

```
ii  libapache2-mod-php7.0              7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php-common                         1:35ubuntu6                         all          Common files for PHP packages
ii  php7.0                             7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php7.0-cli                         7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
ii  php7.0-common                      7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             amd64        documentation, examples and common module for PHP
ii  php7.0-fpm                         7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php7.0-json                        7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             amd64        JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mbstring                    7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             amd64        MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mcrypt                      7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             amd64        libmcrypt module for PHP
ii  php7.0-mysql                       7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             amd64        MySQL module for PHP
ii  php7.0-opcache                     7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
ii  php7.0-readline                    7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1             amd64        readline module for PHP
```

I installed Apache and PHP using

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php7.0
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mysql
```

I tried enabling the the extension by add `extension=mbstring.so` under the PHP tag at the top of the `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` file. I tried using `phpenmod mbstring`. I tried everything I could find.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was because I had uncommented `include_path` and `extension_dir`. Not sure which one caused it, but once I commented those lines again, it worked.